# While loop providing inputs in shell script

Tags: sh

```
while getopts "f:t:d:g:o:p:b:q:r:" opt; do
    case "$opt" in

(f)fan=${OPTARG}
(t)..
 esac
done
shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ));
```

How to provide input?
Can anyone plz tell me how to provide input for the above mentioned code snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer:
We can provide the input like `-f inputvalue`

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts "f:t:d:g:o:p:b:q:r:" opt; do
  case "$opt" in

  f) fan=${OPTARG}
  ;;
  t) echo "doing somthing with option t = $OPTARG"
  ;;
 esac
done
shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ));
```

and run as

```
$ ./script.sh -f admin
doing somthing with option f = admin
```